# Non-differentiable points in a graph: Vertical Tangent vs Vertical Asymptote

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Can someone help me understand the difference between the two?

Vertical tangent at $x = a$: $f$ is continuous at a but $f'(a)$ blows up.
· How is this different from a vertical asymptote?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How do you define vertical asymptote? Why don't you compare the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

For asymptote f is not continuous. think tor exaple tangent function

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a graph to have a vertical tangent.  For example the function $y=\sqrt[3]x$ has the vertical tangent $x=0$ even though its slope $y=dy/dx$ is undefined. Also, the unit circle, defined parametrically as $(\cos t, \sin t)$ has a vertical tangent at $t=n\pi$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ even though its slope $(dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$ is undefined.

A vertical asymptote, on the other hand, is a line of the form $x=a$ where $a\in\Bbb R$ that a function tends to. The function could simply approach the asymptote from either side but not be defined there, as with $y=1/x$, or it could swivel around the asymptote, as with the parametric function $\left( \cos(t)/t , t \right)$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that vertical asymptote in the question refers to functions $f\colon A\to\mathbb R$, for $A\subseteq \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Ennar is $x\mapsto 1/x$ not a $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ mapping?

Comment: Is $t\mapsto (\cos (t)/t,t)$?

Comment: @Ennar No, but I still believe it’s a relevant example that provides insight.

Comment: Yes, I do. For example, $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]x$. I edited because it had a mistake I realized after I already made the comment.

Comment: Well I do not, since OP clearly struggles with basic definitions considering real functions of real variable, adding vector functions is more likely to cause confusion than clarification.

Comment: That’s good! I’ll include that and give you credit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66093/discussion-between-chase-ryan-taylor-and-ennar).

Comment: Nothing to discuss, just please simplify your answer so it is useful to OP, there is no need to give me any credit. Also, my remark was unnecessarily rude, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully compare the definitions, you will see that $f$ has vertical tangent at $a$ when $f'$ has vertical asymptote at $a$. Note that $f$ does not have vertical asymptote at $a$ in that case, since by $f$ "blowing up", we would immediately have that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$.

Answer (score -1):

Two examples:

$$ y= \frac{1}{a-x}$$
has a vertical asymptote at $x=a$, the curvature of the curve goes to zero but slope is infinite. In Control engineering called a **pole**.

$$ y^2= {2 a x-x^2}$$

has a vertical tangents at points $ (x=0, x=2 a) $ on x-axis. Continuously differentiable.

The curvature of the curve remains at $ \dfrac{1}{a},$ and these points are **zeroes**.